# Installing a package with pip in python

Tags: python, numpy, pip, package, installation

```
C:\Program Files\Python 3\Scripts>pip install pywin32

Collecting pywin32

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

I just installed python and I am trying to install packages like numpy using pip in command prompt but I am getting an error. 
I have also tried installing the packages in pycharm but it does not still installing
[pip screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUauH.png)

[pip screen error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfSmH.png)

Comment: try `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: You have an unstable connection to PyPI so `pip` can't search for/download the packages.

Comment: Better use whl, download it and install from the offline wheel file.
Download from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
and then do `pip install /Download/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: will pip install /Download/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl also solve the error i'm getting in pycharm.

Comment: You are still getting the error with above command?